# Export database to Download folder in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, file, export

I read other posts about export data base file in Android but I cant figure out how create or copy this database on Downloader folder.

I use on my Manifest (permissions):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Activity:

I call this function when I press a button but nothing happens (no exceptions and no file copy or created from currentDBPath)

```
public void exportDatabase() {  
    try {
        File download_folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (download_folder.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+"YourWords";
            String backupDBPath = "YourWords";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(download_folder, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**.

To get a `File` object pointing at a database, assuming the database is in the default location, [use `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29).

Also, **NEVER IGNORE EXCEPTIONS**.

Add `Log.e("RuslanApp", "Crash in saving database", e);` to the `catch` block, so you can use LogCat to see what may be going wrong.

Comment: With Toast and using your advice of using Logs: It say to me that file is saved on /storage/sdcard0/Download but I can't see it on my device (
see hidden files are enable).

Comment: @Ruslan: Use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to update the `MediaStore`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Finally, the problem was in add .db in String name file on getDatabasePath().

Thanks for your time and advice